# Why fpclassify() macro is defined in math.h and not in float.h?

Tags: c, floating-point, macros

N2479 C17..C2x working draft — February 5, 2020 ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E):

```
7.12.3.1 The fpclassify macro:
Synopsis
#include <math.h>
int fpclassify(real-floating x);
```

Why `fpclassify()` macro is defined in `math.h` and not in `float.h`?

What is the motivation / rationale / argumentation?

Comment: This macro was added in C99 and the C99 rationale doesn't mention why it (or the group of "classification macros") was placed in math.h specifically.

Comment: Well ... "**Returns:** The fpclassify macro returns the value of the number classification macro appropriate to the value of its argument." and the *number classification macro" is defined in `<math.h>` ... now ask "why `FP_INFINITE`, etc, is defined in `<math.h>`?"

Comment: Because they felt like it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per C 2018 5.2.4.2.2, `float.h` provides “The characteristics of floating types.” Thus, it defines macros that describe the **types**, such as characterizing their precisions and ranges, what radix is used, and so on. All of these are fixed when the C implementation is designed.

`fpclassify` is an operation on a **value**. The result is computed from the argument, so it is a mathematical function of a value, not a characteristic of a floating-point type.

Note also that `<float.h>` and `<limits.h>` are specified separately from the other headers. These two are in the “Environmental limits” section of the C standard, which covers characteristics of C implementations. (They are also listed in “Library” section as stubs that refer to the “Environmental limits” section.)

Comment: @njuffa: No, it did not change; I overlooked that they are also listed in clause 7 (although just as stubs referring to 5.2.4.2). They do just define macros with values, not any functions or objects, so they do not fit the description of the standard headers in 7.1.2 1: “… The header declares a set of related functions, plus any necessary types and additional macros needed to facilitate their use…” But I will delete or reword. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Although I can't speak on behalf of the C Standard Committee members, or *why* they chose one thing over another, what I *can* say is that the `<float.h>` header contains (for the most part) definitions of **compile-time constants** that define any architecture-specific properties (characteristics) of the various floating-point data types.

However, the `<math.h>` header provides the prototypes for functions that comprise the math(s) functions of the C Standard Library, along with associated constants that those functions use and/or return (such as `FP_INFINITE`). Those functions return **run-time** values.

Now, although the Standard defines `fpclassify` as a *macro*, any implementation can only define that in terms of code (most likely involving a function call) that – of necessity – be evaluated at run time. (How else would it cope with a variable given as its argument?)

Comment: *any implementation can only define that in terms of code (most likely involving a function call)*  FWIW, both Linux and Solaris require `-lm` at link time when using `fpclassify()`.  I also suspect the committee strongly considered then-current implementations.  If Sun's, HP's, and GNU/FSF's C environment already had implemented `fpclassify()` in `math.h`, the committee wouldn't have changed that.  I seem to remember that the driving force behind ANSI C/C89 was the codification and standardization of **existing** C, not the creation of new features.  That likely carried over to C99.